# iOS core data "joining" two "tables"

Tags: ios, core-data

I have to Entity in core data:

GAMES and PLAYERS

GAMES - look like this (simplified):
board
userid

PLAYERS
userid
name

PLAYERS is unique

I need to select GAMES and add the PLAYERS.name column to this result.

I have set up all core data and relationships, and can select from the "tables" and put it in a array and in a Tableview.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"GAMES" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
GamesARRAY =[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

and so on....

But HOW do i select, or access the data from players table? I know all the basics and theory, but I really need code examples. Not just answers like: use NSSet or like that..

Answer (score 2):

CoreData is not a database.

Let me repeat that again.

### CoreData is not a database.

Don't think of it like one.

CoreData is a object relationship graph management and persistence framework.

If you want to access players from a given game, why are you using a `userid` field in both entities? You should just use a CoreData relationship instead. That way you don't even have to think about it, you just access the relationship property on your game and you get back your player, and vice versa.

You should also rename your entity. GAMES and PLAYERS might make sense as table names, but you're not going to want to have a `GAMES*` object lying around in your code that represents one game. Why not just name them `Game` and `Player`?

Comment: I know its not a database. Thats why I wrote "joining" and "tables" (in quotation).

Comment: @Romo: You're still thinking of it like a database. Don't even do that. Just set up a relationship between your two entities and access the relationship through its property in your code.

Comment: Yes I do know all about the theory. I just cant make it work? But thanks anyway..

Comment: @Romo: Well, what have you tried? Ditch the `userid` field. Just make a relationship between your two entities in the .xcdatamodel editor. Assuming it's a one-to-many relationship, the Game will have a property that, when accessed, returns a Player, and the Player will have a property that, when accessed, returns an `NSSet` of Games.

Comment: Let me ask otherwise: In my GamesARRAY that a have - how do I access the player.name value? I can access all values from GAMES and the relationship property (or what it is called?), but not the "name" itself...

Comment: @Romo: if your `GAMES` has a relationship called `player` which returns the `PLAYERS` object, for an individual `GAMES*` you can say `game.player.name`. If you want the name of each player associated with a game in your array, you can use `-valueForKeyPath:` as a convenience method, as in `[GamesARRAY valueForKeyPath:@"player.name"]`, which will give you back an array containing the value for that key path on every element of your original array.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It gives me an error, but that means I am missing something. But your answer gave me at least the goal to when it should work. :-) BTW: How does my Entity select know that userid=userid in those to Entities?

Comment: @Romo It doesn't. Which is why you want to delete `userid` entirely, as I've told you several times. You cannot define your own foreign keys. The relationship does it all for you under the hood.

Comment: My mistake is that I added the data separately, and not in some object class thing?

Comment: @Romo: I'm not really understanding what you mean. In the Core Data model editor in Xcode, you can add a relationship directly to your `GAMES` entity that links to your `PLAYERS` entity.

Comment: Yes, I did that already. Well.... must say, I just do not understand how it works. How it can match userid to userid without userid when i add a PLAYER.. I have tried to figure this out in full 4 days now. I have search, downloaded project, and tried out everything. I give up... But thanks Kevin.

Comment: @Romo: What are you confused about? You're not creating a database schema. You're creating an entity description. CoreData does whatever it wants to under the hood to make it work. In the case of the SQLite backend, it will indeed use a foreign key and a JOIN (and a separate table in the case of many-to-many), but you don't ever have to look at that. All you have to know is you have a relationship.

Comment: Technically I do understand, but I just can't make it work. Thats why my main question was code examples. I already have tried putting pieces of code together from all over the web without success. Simple simple code example of insert/update/delete/fetch of two tables with relationship would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have a relationship on `GAMES` that knows a `PLAYERS` entity? If so, for any `GAMES` object you can traverse that relationship (`game.player`) to get the properties of a game's player object. We don't do JOINs as such in Core Data; Core Data uses relationships to abstract away things like foreign keys and JOINs (even though these are done behind the scenes in the SQLite backend, for example).

Also, as Kevin notes, `GAMES` and `PLAYERS` break sensible naming conventions for Core Data entities. `Game` and `Player` are much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[game valueForKey:@"player"] valueForKey:@"name"]
```

Or, if you have set up the relevant classes,

```
game.player.name
```