# How to join two core data tables?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have the following two tables where I want to join a number of markers to a single race. How do I do this in SwiftUI and core data?

I can't seem to find any detailed description of how to join tables.[image]

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769333/ios-core-data-joining-two-tables .

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but it doesn’t answer my question. I’m coming from this with dB knowledge, I don’t understand how core data creates the relationship. Both Race and Marker have not been created, so I’m in the chicken vs the egg scenario. Let’s say I create a race, do I save it and then race.markers = Marker(...)? Or do I save both race and marker then race.markers = marker?

Comment: You can do it either way. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the guide there are two options
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html

`anEmployee.department = newDepartment`
or
`newDepartment.mutableSetValueForKey("employees").addObject(employee)`

After you do that you just save the changes with the default `save()`

The `relationships` are `variables` in the objects.